# Is there any place where one could observe real project ceremonies such as stand ups, retros, planning?

Tags: scrum, agile, project-team

My mentee asked if there’s a website, where you can see real project events, like daily’s , retro, planning, etc. so that juniors could seen how exactly it works.

I assume no, because of NDA. But maybe there is?

Comment: Maybe this person could attend actual scrum ceremonies in his/her workplace as an observer?

Comment: I know this does not answer the question your mentee asked, but it may be the answer they need:

Looking at random real project events is not a good idea to find out "how it works". 

They will most likely see many errors, bad practices and other things that would be bad examples for someone new to scrum.

Answer (score 3):

I doubt that you'll actually find 'the real thing' (because who wants to share their development details?) but if you search for relevant terms on YouTube you find material that comes close.

E.g. searching for [daily standup](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=daily+standup) has a result [Agile Simulation - Part 20 | The Daily Standup](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q_R9wQY4G5I), which gives you a pretty good impression of how a daily standup can/'should' go (It's a training video where they discuss what's going on).

As is clear from the title, this one is part of a small series [Agile Simulation Videos](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLBF7FCBE7E2ECF1FB)

Happy hunting for other videos...

Comment: Thanks for sharing it Jan. That actually look a bit made up to me. And I didn’t googled anything proper. You are probably right saying no one would like to share that, but it was worth asking though :)